Adding path inside gradle.properties file in Android Studio
Am trying to solve the following problem:
I keep getting  unsupported class file major version 61 error on Android studio!
By following the link: link
I see I can change the android.jetifier.blacklist property inside the gradle.properties file.
From the stack trace I know the path of the file that is causing problems. However, when I try
to change the android.jetifier.blacklist = C:\users\something\something\something\problem.aar
the gradle.properties file is not recognizing the '' character.
I tried enclosing the path in " " AND nothing  ALSO,  I enclosed the path in ' ' AND nothing!
I have also tried just putting the name of the problem file AND its not working!
How can I add this path to the gradle.properties file?

Ok its very simple. Just type the name of the aar file that is causing problems. So, just do this with not " "  OR  ' '  android.jetifier.blacklist = problem_file.aar
